# How do I see the list of all variables in scope along with their values in Javascript using the Developer Tools on Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scope, developer-tools

I tried using the following and it does give me a list of variables in scope. I also need to see their values on the console. Is it possible?

```
for(var b in window) { 
    if (window.hasOwnProperty(b)) 
        console.log(b);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of `b` in `window` using the bracket notation `window[b]`:

```
for(var b in window)
{ 
  if(window.hasOwnProperty(b)) {
    console.log(b);
    console.log(window[b]);
  }
}
```